# Pandoc Markdown to PDF, and SVG image causing "xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object."?

Tags: pdf, svg, markdown, pandoc

Consider the following Markdown document, `notes.md`:

```
# Notes

Here some notes about including **SVG** remotely:

I have found this image:

[![Dodecahedron_schlegel](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Dodecahedron_schlegel.svg)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Dodecahedron_schlegel.svg)

... and I'd like to have in included in the PDF via `pandoc` ...

<!-- [![RS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/RS-485_waveform.svg)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/RS-485_waveform.svg) -->
```

If I try to compile this to PDF via `pandoc` with `xelatex`:

```
pandoc notes.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o notes.pdf
```

everything is fine, no errors, and image is visible in the pdf:

[image: pandoc-to-pdf-OK]

Now, if I uncomment the second line - which also is a link to an SVG image from wikimedia.org - and I try to compile, I get a *massive* number of errors, and no (new) PDF produced (full log is [here](https://gist.github.com/sdbbs/d9a9a38534dc83a9c59d6d4aaaaf774d)):

```
$ pandoc notes.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o notes.pdf

xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object.

No output PDF file written.

xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object.

No output PDF file written.
Error producing PDF.
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.7.9)  7 DEC 2020 09:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**C://msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/input.tex
(C:/msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/input.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(C:/bin/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(C:/bin/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163

...

Package fontspec Info: latinmodern-math scale = 0.9998964600422715.


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'latinmodern-math.otf(3)' created for font
(fontspec)             'latinmodern-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Scale=MatchLowercase,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},Sm
allCapsFont={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.5-},{Size=6-8.5,Font=latinmode
rn-math.otf,Style=MathScript},{Size=-6,Font=latinmodern-math.otf,Style=MathScri
ptScript}},BoldFont={latinmodern-math.otf},ScaleAgain=0.9999,FontAdjustment={\f
ontdimen
(fontspec)             8\font =0.4pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =2.0pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =1.67pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =1.11pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =6.0pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =0pt\relax }].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.5->s*[0.9998964600422715]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:s
cript=math;language=dflt;"<6-8.5>s*[0.9998964600422715]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/
OT:script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=0;"<-6>s*[0.9998964600422715]"[latinmodern-m
ath.otf]/OT:script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 8\font =0.4pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font
(fontspec)             =2.0pt\relax \fontdimen 10\font =1.67pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 11\font =1.11pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font
(fontspec)             =6.0pt\relax \fontdimen 13\font =0pt\relax
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[0.9998964600422715]"[latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:scri
pt=math;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 8\font =0.4pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font
(fontspec)             =2.0pt\relax \fontdimen 10\font =1.67pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 11\font =1.11pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font
(fontspec)             =6.0pt\relax \fontdimen 13\font =0pt\relax

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 6
3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/lmex/m/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(3)/m/n on inpu
t line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 63.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/lmex/m/n --> TU/latinmodern-math.otf(3)/b/n on inpu
t line 63.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box49
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 63.

(C:/bin/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:/bin/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:/bin/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count283
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 63.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 63.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 63.
File: C://msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/ce60773d6c257b0c33bde80c372cc790
8f36edaa.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use C://msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/ce60773d6c257b0c33bde80c372cc7908
f36edaa.pdf>
File: C://msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/5977a217a848816000aa43663baa452f
be03f979.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use C://msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/5977a217a848816000aa43663baa452fb
e03f979.pdf>
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 79.
[1

]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 79.
 (C:\/msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/input.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 79.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 79.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 79.
 )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you useC:
 16163 strings out of 480251
 288174 string characters out of 5899096
 720292 words of memory out of 5000000
 33615 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532998 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 622 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 53i,5n,118p,343b,316s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;
file C:\/msys64/tmp/tex2pdf.-b632e90b0d54cf19/input.pdf may not be valid.
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this - so I could also include that other image in the PDF using pandoc?

Comment: The first SVG does not contain any text, the second does. It seems the conversion process is having trouble with text fonts.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error output:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)) [1] [2]
Chapter 1.
[3] [4]
Chapter 2.
[5] [6]
Chapter 3.
[7] [8] [9] [10]
Chapter 4.
[11]
Overfull \hbox (4.64401pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 182--189
[]\TU/Inter(0)/m/n/10 This makes the use of \TU/Inter(0)/m/it/10 CTRL \TU/Inter
(0)/m/n/10 key combinations more ergonomic. 
[12] [13]
Overfull \hbox (2.98775pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 205--212
\TU/Inter(0)/m/n/10 reachable through the OLED menu. Each cell icon corresponds
 
[14] [15] [16]
Chapter 5.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
Overfull \hbox (15.37852pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 251--258
\TU/Inter(0)/m/n/10 for your computer to execute, but also to write programs (s
cripts) 
[17]
xdvipdfmx:fatal: pdf_link_obj(): passed invalid object.

No output PDF file written.
```

The page in question in my latex also used pdf figures.

The problem went away after installing the ghostscript package (I am running Debian).